# How to use parallel with curl?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, gnome-terminal

How do i use gnu parallel to make this process faster ?

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=1; c<=100; c++ ))
do  
    curl -sS 'https://example.com' \
        --data 'value='$c'' /dev/null
    echo $c
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parallel, or xargs

```
seq 100 | parallel curl -sS 'https://example.com' --data value='{}' /dev/null
seq 100 | xargs -I{} curl -sS 'https://example.com' --data value='{}' /dev/null
```

As the script stand, output will be sent to stdout. With xargs, this will result in output from different calls potentially mixed. Consider redirect output to files for additional processing, if needed.

You can add options for max parallel (-Pn, etc.) as needed

I'm not sure why '/dev/null' is needed. Consider reordering:

> curl -sS --data value='{}' https://example.com'

Comment: You can make use of persistent connection to make the request even faster.

Comment: As much as I know, possible to use persistent connection with curl (and wget) on GET calls. Not sure how to use persistent connection when POST, where each call need different -data. Can you provide example ?

Comment: Yeah, curl can not send POST requests with different data without dropping the connection, even with -K, which just adds-up all the `--data` and send them to all `--url`s. If it's not required for the `value` be unique, we can generate a number of config files containing a batch of URLs and run them in parallel with `xargs -P`.to minimize connect cost.